# Skorohod theorem (weak convergence) on a discrete setting

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a question about the application of Skorohod representation theorem. The questions arises in this [paper](http://www.math.ethz.ch/%7Ehmsoner/pdfs/82-Soner-Dolinsky-transactions.pdf) about robust hedging in mathematical finance. It is about the very last equation on page 15. The question is about the application of Skorohod representation theorem. I've asked this question on MSE, but no answer was given up to now. I've also discussed this with a lot of my colleagues but nobody was able to provide a solution. It would really be appreciated if someone could tell me the solution.

Let me introduce all the notation such that the question is self-contained.

We have $\Omega = \mathbb{R}_+^N$ and define $S=(S_1,\dots,S_N)$ as the canonical stochastic process with $S_i(\omega)=\omega_i$ for $\omega=(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_N)\in\Omega$.

Let $\mathcal{H}=\{f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R} \text{ continuous }:|f(x)|\le C(1+x^p)\}$ for a $p>2$. Now the paper uses a certain discretization of this setting:
$$U_n:=\left\{\frac{k}{n}:k=0,1,\dots\right\}$$
$$\mathcal{H}_n:=\{f:U_n\to\mathbb{R} :|f(x)|\le C(1+x^p)\}$$ and $$\Omega_n=(U_n)^N$$
Two last definitions,
$$\mathcal{W}_n:=\left\{f\in\mathcal{H}_n:\|f\|_*:=\sup_{x\in U_n}\frac{|f(x)|}{(1+x^p)}\le n\right\}.$$
Moreover we have the set $\mathcal{D_n}$ of probability measure $Q$ supported on $\Omega_n$ such that
$$E_Q[\|S\|^p]<\infty$$
where $\|\omega\|:=\max_{1\le i\le N}|\omega_i|$

In the paper they prove the existence of a sequence of probability measures $\{Q_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ with $Q_n\in\mathcal{D}_n$ which converges weakly to a probability measure $\tilde{Q}$. To obtain weak convergence, the authors prove tightness of $\{Q_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Tightness follows from the following condition
$$\lim_{A\to\infty}\sup_nE_{Q_n}[S_k\mathbf1_{S_k>A}]=0,\forall k=1,\dots,N-1$$
Moreover we know
$$\sup_nE_{Q_n}[S_N^p]<\infty$$

For $g\in\mathcal{H}$ let $f_n=g|_{U_n}$, hence $g$ and $f_n$ agree on $U_n$. Clearly for large $n$ we have $f_n\in\mathcal{W}_n$. By continuity of $g$ we have $g(x)=\lim_n f_n(x_n)$ for every sequence $x_n\ge 0$ converging to $x$.

> **Question:** using Skorohod representation theorem we have $$E_{\tilde{Q}}[g(S_N)]=\lim_n E_{Q_n}[f_n(S_N)]=\lim_n E_{Q_n}[g(S_N)]$$

The second equality is clear by definition of $f_n$. However how can we apply the Skorohod representation theorem? We know there exists another probability space $(\Omega',\mathcal{A}, P)$, a sequence of r.v. $X_n:\Omega'\to\Omega$ converging to $X$ for all $\omega'\in\Omega$. The law of $X$ is given by $Q$ and the law of $X_n$ is given by $Q_n$. Therefore we have

- $E_Q[g(S_N)]=E_P[g(S_N(X))]$
- $E_{Q_n}[g(S_N)]=E_P[g(S_N(X_n))]$

By continuity of $g$ we have $E_P[g(S_N(X))]=E_P[\lim_ng(S_N(X_n))]$. However, why can we interchange the limit and the expecatation? We have no integrability condition on $(\Omega',\mathcal{A},P)$.

Comment: Something doesn't seem to be right with your definition of $\mathcal{W}_n$.  Anyway, it seems to me that we are supposed to show the uniform integrability (under $P$) of $\{g(S_N(X_n))\}$, which since it is just a statement about their distributions, would follow from the uniform integrability under $Q_n$ of $g(S_N)$.  It's sufficient to find a uniform bound on their $L^r$ norms for some $r > 1$, but I don't quite see how to get that from the given conditions.  If we had something like $|g(x)| \le C(1+x^{p-\epsilon})$ I think it would work.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for you comment. I edited my question. I was also trying to prove uniform integrability. All we know is $\lim_{A\to\infty}\sup_{n}E_{Q_n}E[S_k\mathbf1_{Sk>A}]=0$ for all $k=0,…,N−1$. This is stated in the same proof before equation (3.17). But this estimate is used to prove tightness of the $\{Q_n\}$

Comment: I suggest asking Prof. Darrell Duffie about this. He is very good at mathematical rigor in finance.